# Compiler Differences Between Different Builds of Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 after using 2017. I have a vb.net web api application that I develop for and every since I started building the project in 2019, I am receiving errors that never occurred before in 2017. I have previously working code that was performing a null check and count greater than 0 check on a dictionary (dictionary1?.Count > 0). This code is failing to check for nothing and my next check is throwing Object Reference must be set to an instance of an object because my dictionary is nothing. It only seems to happen when I build it with 2019 on my computer. None of my team members appear to have this same issue. Does anyone know what I could have missed in the install? Do I need to reinstall 2019 to fix the issue?

Edit
[Null Reference Exception Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4JNh.jpg)

Comment: Please show me a screenshot of the debugger stopped on a thrown NullRef as a result of that code evaluating to true inside an If

Comment: I added a screenshot to my initial post. You can see that it should have skipped the dctExistingSpecs.ContainsKey(newSpecKVP.Key) check since it never should have gotten past the first check.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/69

Comment: That's interesting. Do you have any information for me as to why this works when compiled by the majority of my team, but why it doesn't work (or is working correctly as explained in that post) when I compile the project? I can also build the same project in 2017, and that line of code works as I was expecting.

Comment: Sounds like it might be an idea to have you and another team member build this code and look at the IL. Different MSBuild versions in use perhaps?

Comment: We've narrowed this issue down to an update in visual studio 2019. Somewhere between versions 16.4.5 and 16.5.3 we start seeing issues. We have opened up a ticket through Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some issues with VB.NET solution files in 2019 that I did NOT have with 2017. I never could figure out what was wrong exactly, so I created a "new" project in 2019, and then just copied by code in into the new project. It was a pain, but it worked. So far I've been on 2019 without any further issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very large project that does work for the majority of our team members. Creating a new one isn't really in the cards.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code on VS 2017 and 2019, in an netcore (2019) and netstd472 (both 2017 and 2019) app:

```
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim d As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing
    Dim k As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) = Nothing


    If d?.Count > 0 AndAlso d.ContainsKey(k.Key) Then

    End If

End Sub
```

None of them throw an exception.

Here's the generated IL for the netstd, built with 2017's `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework`:

```
.method public static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       51 (0x33)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string> d,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string> k,
           [2] bool V_2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloca.s   k
  IL_0005:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>
  IL_000b:  ldloc.0
  IL_000c:  brtrue.s   IL_0011
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000f:  br.s       IL_001a
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  call       instance int32 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::get_Count()
  IL_0017:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0018:  cgt
  IL_001a:  brfalse.s  IL_002b
  IL_001c:  ldloc.0
  IL_001d:  ldloca.s   k
  IL_001f:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>::get_Key()
  IL_0024:  callvirt   instance bool class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::ContainsKey(!0)
  IL_0029:  br.s       IL_002c
  IL_002b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_002c:  stloc.2
  IL_002d:  ldloc.2
  IL_002e:  brfalse.s  IL_0031
  IL_0030:  nop
  IL_0031:  nop
  IL_0032:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Main
```

and for the netcore31 built with 2019's `Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework`:

```
.method public static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       51 (0x33)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string> V_0,
           valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string> V_1,
           bool V_2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_0005:  initobj    valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>
  IL_000b:  ldloc.0
  IL_000c:  brtrue.s   IL_0011
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000f:  br.s       IL_001a
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  call       instance int32 class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::get_Count()
  IL_0017:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0018:  cgt
  IL_001a:  brfalse.s  IL_002b
  IL_001c:  ldloc.0
  IL_001d:  ldloca.s   V_1
  IL_001f:  call       instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>::get_Key()
  IL_0024:  callvirt   instance bool class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::ContainsKey(!0)
  IL_0029:  br.s       IL_002c
  IL_002b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_002c:  stloc.2
  IL_002d:  ldloc.2
  IL_002e:  brfalse.s  IL_0031
  IL_0030:  nop
  IL_0031:  nop
  IL_0032:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Hope it's of some use

#### Update

Though the above code doesn't crash, this does:

```
Sub Main(args As String())

    Dim d As Dictionary(Of String, String) = Nothing
    Dim k As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) = Nothing

    Dim x = d?.Count > 0
    If x AndAlso d.ContainsKey(k.Key) Then

    End If

End Sub
```

Here's the IL:

```
.method public static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       112 (0x70)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string> d,
           [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string> k,
           [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> x,
           [3] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> V_3,
           [4] bool V_4,
           [5] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> V_5)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldloca.s   k
  IL_0005:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>
  IL_000b:  ldloc.0
  IL_000c:  brtrue.s   IL_0019
  IL_000e:  ldloca.s   V_3
  IL_0010:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
  IL_0016:  ldloc.3
  IL_0017:  br.s       IL_0027
  IL_0019:  ldloc.0
  IL_001a:  call       instance int32 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::get_Count()
  IL_001f:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0020:  cgt
  IL_0022:  newobj     instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_0027:  stloc.2
  IL_0028:  ldloc.2
  IL_0029:  dup
  IL_002a:  stloc.3
  IL_002b:  stloc.s    V_5
  IL_002d:  ldloca.s   V_5
  IL_002f:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::get_HasValue()
  IL_0034:  brfalse.s  IL_003f
  IL_0036:  ldloca.s   V_3
  IL_0038:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
  IL_003d:  brfalse.s  IL_0059
  IL_003f:  ldloc.0
  IL_0040:  ldloca.s   k
  IL_0042:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<string,string>::get_Key()
  IL_0047:  callvirt   instance bool class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string,string>::ContainsKey(!0)
  IL_004c:  brtrue.s   IL_0056
  IL_004e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_004f:  newobj     instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_0054:  br.s       IL_0057
  IL_0056:  ldloc.3
  IL_0057:  br.s       IL_005f
  IL_0059:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_005a:  newobj     instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::.ctor(!0)
  IL_005f:  stloc.3
  IL_0060:  ldloca.s   V_3
  IL_0062:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>::GetValueOrDefault()
  IL_0067:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_0069:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_006b:  brfalse.s  IL_006e
  IL_006d:  nop
  IL_006e:  nop
  IL_006f:  ret
} // end of method Module1::Main
```

I don't really have an explanation though

Comment: We've narrowed this issue down to an update in visual studio 2019. Somewhere between versions 16.4.5 and 16.5.3 we start seeing issues. We have opened up a ticket through Microsoft.